# java StreamTokenizer wordChars() and nextToken()

Tags: java

This might be a dumb question but I am having a hard time recognizing how StreamTokenizer delimit input streams. Is it delimited by space and nextline? I am also confused with the use of wordChars(). For example:

```
public static int getSet(String workingDirectory, String filename, List<String> set) {
    int cardinality = 0;
    File file = new File(workingDirectory,filename);
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        StreamTokenizer text = new StreamTokenizer(in);
        text.wordChars('_','_');
        text.nextToken();
        while (text.ttype != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
            set.add(text.sval);
            cardinality++;
//              System.out.println(cardinality + " " + text.sval);
            text.nextToken();
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cardinality; 
}
```

If the text file includes such string:A_B_C D_E_F.

Does text.wordChars('_','_') mean only underscore will be considered as valid words?

And what will the tokens be in this case?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/StreamTokenizer.html)? What can you find out by experimenting with it in practice?

Answer (score 1):

`how StreamTokenizer delimit input streams. Is it delimited by space and nextline?`

Short Answer is **Yes**

The parsing process is controlled by a table and a number of flags that can be set to various states. The stream tokenizer can recognize identifiers, numbers, quoted strings, and various comment styles. In addition, an instance has four flags. One of the **flags** indicate that whether line terminators are to be returned as tokens or **treated as white space that merely separates tokens.**

`Does text.wordChars('_','_') mean only underscore will be considered as valid words?`

Short Answer is **Yes**

`WordChars` takes two inputs. First(`low`) is lower end for the character set and second(`high`) is upper end of the character set. If `low` is passed with the value less than `0` then it will be set to `0`. Since you are passing `_ = 95`, lower end will be accepted as `_=95`. If high is passed less than `255` then it is accepted as the high end of the character set range. Since you are passing high as `_=95`, this is also accepted. Now when it tries to determine the range of characters from `low-to-high`, it finds only one character, which is `_` itself. In that case, `_` will be the only character recognized as word character.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
Pattern splitRegex = Pattern.compile("_");
String[] tokens = splitRegex.split(stringtobesplitedbydelimeter);
```

or you can also use

```
   String[] tokens = stringtobesplitedbydelimeter.split('_')
```